# How List copy Set in Java?

Tags: java, list, collections, set

[image]

I tested below code. I expected compile error because I ordered compiler to copy "Set<>". In detail, "Hashmap.keySet()" returns "Set<>" not a "List<>". I used to know that "Set<>" is not compatible with "List<>" based on above the structure. Could you let me know how this code work?

```
        List<String> h = new ArrayList<String>(HashMap<>.keySet());
```

Comment: [The `ArrayList` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-) accepts any `Collection`. Any collection can be iterated through, so the constructor can iterate through the collection and add every element to the list.

Comment: Exactly what khelwood says. The `ArrayList`'s constructor simply takes the elements in the order the iterator of the `Collection` returns them. As `Set` is a subclass of `Collection` it works just fine.

Comment: `HashMap<>.keySet()` this is incorrect. You are calling `keySet`, an instance method, as if it were a static method.

Comment: Thank you for explanation guys>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HashMap<>.keySet()` returns a `Set`. A `Set` is a `Collection`. `ArrayList` has a constructor that accepts a `Collection` and adds all the elements of the `Collection` to the `List`. Therefore you can pass `HashMap<>.keySet()` to that constructor.

> **java.util.ArrayList.ArrayList(Collection c)**
>
> Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection, in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator.

Comment: Thanks. You've very helpful Eran.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of `ArrayList` used in that code takes a `Collection`, which a `Set` is.

Answer (score 1):

The [constructor of ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(java.util.Collection)) used in that code takes a Collection, which a Set is.

Inside the ArrayList constructor, they are converting the collection to an array. In the ArrayList, they used Object[] to store objects.

Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection, in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator.

```
public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
     elementData = c.toArray();
     size = elementData.length;
     // c.toArray might (incorrectly) not return Object[] (see 6260652)
     if (elementData.getClass() != Object[].class)
        elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, Object[].class);
}
```

Comment: Thank your specific explanation. I understood.